# Thymeleaf + spring пагинация

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

```
@RequestMapping({"/",""})
public String greeting() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping (value = "/tables")
public String getValues(Model model,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page)
{
  model.addAttribute("listPlaces",repo.viewPage(page));
  model.addAttribute("currentPage",page);
    return "tables";
}
@GetMapping (value = "/second_page")
public String show()
{

    return "second_page";
}
@GetMapping (value = "/index")
public String showIndex()
{
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(Places place) {
    repo.save(place);
    return "redirect:/tables";
}
@PostMapping("/delete")
public String delete(Long id) {
    repo.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/tables";
}
@GetMapping("/findId")
@ResponseBody
public Places findOne(Integer id)
{
    id = 1;
    return repo.get(id);
}
```

```html
</table>
        <hr/>
        <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
            <li class = "nav-item" th:each = " i : ${#numbers.sequence(0,listPlaces.totalPages-1)}">
            <a th:href = "@{/(page=${i})}" th:text = "${i}" class = "nav-link"
            th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'active':''">
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</body>
</div>
```

Здравствуйте, не получается вывести таблицу под другими номерами страниц, перенаправляет на исходный адрес и подписывает page =2, собственно нужно чтобы выводило на странице таблиц, заранее благодарю)

Comment: Не совсем понятно как Вы на страницы разбиваете данные. Обычно в Spring это делают с помощью PagingAndSortingRepository

Comment: Смотрел иностранный канал на ютубе, там все работает при такой схеме, правда все происходит на одной странице, а у меня их три и при нажатии на выбранную страницу перекидывает на index и подписывается номер страницы в адресной строке

Comment: дело в том, чтобы разбить что-то на страницы, должен быть массив/коллекция, с которой порционно будут выдаваться записи, соответствующие нужной странице.

Comment: коллекция возвращается методом findall который находится в методе viewpage

Comment: так Page<...> findAll(Pageable pageable)?

Comment: public Page viewPage(int page)
    {
        return repo.findAll(PageRequest.of(page,15));
    }

Comment: Если я сам в адресной строке укажу конкретную страницу то все работает

Comment: Значит проблема в thymeleaf

Comment: Да,такой коварной ошибки я не ожидал, спасибо)))